# Why doesn't Carl use the pill to either replace or take out Eddie?

Tags: plot-explanation, limitless

Carl has a supply of the drug, so why does he need Eddie to run for president, instead of putting his own candidate (on pills) in the running? Alternatively, why doesn't he either use the pills himself or give them to one of his minions so that he can take out Eddie like he threatened.

Comment: I don't remember it being noted that Carl had a supply, but merely killed Eddie's supply (supposedly). Unless I missed something.

Comment: @TylerShads: If Carl doesn't have a supply, how can he be offering Eddie an unlimited supply of the drug in return for political favours?

Comment: I think he was getting at that he controls Eddie's supply now (or so he thinks).  For whatever reason, it doesn't seem like Carl himself takes the drug, most likely because he knew it would be addictive/kill him like his competitor.  Little did he know that (supposedly) Eddie has the drug in his system naturally and permanently (and seemingly more potent).

Comment: Put that in an answer @TylerShads

Comment: @Casebash - its been quite some time since the question and the answer were given. Was there something that you had a concern about?

Answer (score 5):

Let me do the honors...

> I think he was getting at that he controls Eddie's supply now (or so he thinks). For whatever reason, it doesn't seem like Carl himself takes the drug, most likely because he knew it would be addictive/kill him like his competitor. Little did he know that (supposedly) Eddie has the drug in his system naturally and permanently (and seemingly more potent). - @TylerShads

Comment: I laughed a little. I think that guy you quoted is a crackpot conspiracy theorist